# Path Variable and script's shebang will not run correct version of python

Tags: bash, python, gnu-screen

### Problem Statement:

A bash script is being used to create a new screen session for each name from a list of names.  At every name, a python script is run using that name as an input.  The bash script sets the path containing the correct version of python (python 3 in the anaconda package):

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin/python:$PATH

while read p; do
  screen -dm -S $p bash -c "cd /inside/home/thjmatth/essential; python3 essentialpairs_ttest_tissue_1.py; exec sh"
done <cells.txt
```

Setting the path as above didn't allow the correct version of python to run, so I added the following shebang to the python script to run:

```
#!~/anaconda3/bin/python python3
```

Still no dice: `/usr/bin/python` is still being used when it shouldn't.  How can I have this program run the version of python according to the path I specify?

### Attempt 1:

new shebang:

```
#!/inside/home/thjmatth/anaconda3/bin/python/
```

new bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin/python:$PATH

while read p; do
  screen -dm -S $p bash -c "cd /inside/home/thjmatth/essential; python3 essentialpairs_ttest_tissue_1.py; exec sh"
done <cells.txt
```

new permissions on the python script:

```
chmod +x essentialpairs_ttest_tissue_1.py
```

error:

```
bash: python3: command not found
```

running which python in that screen still shows `/usr/bin/python`

### Solution:

Same as Attempt 1 above, but changed line 3 of the bash script to make it a directory rather than an executable:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin/python:$PATH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin/python:$PATH
```

This seems like the path to an executable. `PATH` should contain directories:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

---

```
#!~/anaconda3/bin/python python3
```

1. Shebang lines need actual paths and do not perform [tilde expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) (that's in your shell). Write the actual path to the executable, starting with `/`.
2. This shebang line would be running `~/anaconda3/bin/python` with the argument `python3`, followed by the script name. You probably don't want that, but instead to run either `python` or `python3`.

   ```
   #!/home/thomas/anaconda3/bin/python
   ```

---

```
screen -dm -S $p bash -c "cd /inside/home/thjmatth/essential; python3 essentialpairs_ttest_tissue_1.py; exec sh"
```

If you were still running this line after updating the shebang line, it would be ignored; the `python3` from your `PATH` (which is not the same as `python`!) would be executed and would run the script in turn, and would just skip the shebang line as a comment. If you make the script executable (`chmod +x essentialpairs_ttest_tissue_1.py`), you could run it directly:

```
./essentialpairs_ttest_tissue_1.py
```

and the shebang line would be processed.

---

In this case, you can *probably* get away with just fixing the `PATH` variable from the first section, unless you have Bash startup configuration that resets the variable. If the executable name is `python`, make sure you update your `screen` command line to use that instead of `python3` as well.

Comment: When I `which python` in another environment, it returns `~/anaconda3/bin/python`, so isn't ok to use that when setting the path in my bash script?

Comment: No, you need to use the path to the directory to have command lookup find it there. You can't put an executable itself directly into the path.

Comment: You're right: changing the PATH to be a directory containing the executable rather than the executable itself was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### Possible solution

regarding your second attempt, with the shebang in the python script:

- You can't use `~` in a shebang;
  it has to be the actual path (`#!/inside/home/thjmatth/...`).
- There shouldn’t be a space between the directory name and the program name;
  it has to be `#!/inside/home/thjmatth/anaconda3/bin/python/python3`.

**Sanity check:** Do you have a directory called
`/inside/home/thjmatth/anaconda3/bin/python` that contains
an executable program called `python3`
(i.e., the full pathname to the interpreter program is
`/inside/home/thjmatth/anaconda3/bin/python/python3`?

#### Something to try

Change your script to do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin/python:$PATH

while read p; do
  type python3
  screen -dm -S "$p" bash -c "type python3; exec sh"
done <cells.txt
```

and see if you can figure out what’s happening. 
If you’re still stuck,
edit your question to include the output of the above.

**Another thing:**
You should always quote all references to shell variables (e.g., `"$p"`)
unless you have a good reason not to,
and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.